# Why when checking if string not exist and only then add it to a list there are still duplications?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the variable result for example I have:

"2023_03_15_11_50"

and it's part of a link in m.Value:

[https://something.com/7c4bbe_c8be14c442b74430b94a983613275e0e~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_512,h_512,al_c,q_85,enc_auto/2023_03_15_11_50.png](https://something.com/7c4bbe_c8be14c442b74430b94a983613275e0e%7Emv2.png/v1/fill/w_512,h_512,al_c,q_85,enc_auto/2023_03_15_11_50.png)

but even if I'm checking to add only if "2023_03_15_11_50" not exist in the end still there are two items in the links list with the same "2023_03_15_11_50"

two different links but they are containing in the end "2023_03_15_11_50"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.ProgressBar;
using System.Xml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Strings
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<string> links = new List<string>();
        private string htmlCode = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetLinks();
        }

        private void GetLinks()
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://somesite.com");
            }


            var linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var rawString = htmlCode;
            foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(rawString))
            {
                if (m.Value.EndsWith("png"))
                {
                    if (!links.Contains(m.Value))
                    {
                        int index = m.Value.LastIndexOf("/");
                        int index1 = m.Value.LastIndexOf(".png");
                        string result = m.Value.Substring(index + 1, index1 - index - 1);
                        if (!links.Contains(result))
                        {
                            links.Add(m.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `links.Contains(result)` only checks if `result` is in the list, but the list actually contains URLs, so it returns false anyway.

You need to store both `result` and URL in a collection, for example you can replace the list with a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> links = new();
```

Code in the `GetLinks` method need be changed to:

```
if (!links.ContainsValue(m.Value))
{
    int index = m.Value.LastIndexOf("/");
    int index1 = m.Value.LastIndexOf(".png");
    string result = m.Value.Substring(index + 1, index1 - index - 1);

    /** .net core **/
    links.TryAdd(result, m.Value);

    /** .net framework
    if(!links.ContainsKey(result))
        links.Add(result, m.Value); **/
}
```

Comment: links.TryAdd(result, m.Value); not exist the TryAdd not exist it's giving me error: 'Dictionary<string, string>' does not contain a definition for 'TryAdd' and no accessible extension method 'TryAdd' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string, string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I changed the language to 9.0 still getting this error on the TryAdd: 'Dictionary<string, string>' does not contain a definition for 'TryAdd' and no accessible extension method 'TryAdd' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string, string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `TryAdd` code is for .Net Core, if you are using .Net Framework, use the code that was commented out later.

Comment: `links[result] = m.Value;` works in both versions and is faster than checking `ContainsKey` first

Comment: @Charlieface But it will overwrite the old value, which is different from the logic of the original code.